# Mandrill : use unsubscribe without template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mandrill

I've noticed that my company uses several kinds of emails with Mandrill. Some are generated using Mandrill's templates, and some use our own html (from Rails views).

In our Mandrill templates, we have this :

```
<a href="*|UNSUB|*">[...]</a>
```

Which takes users to `our_subdomain.list-manage1.com/unsubscribe`, with some parameters.

But apparently, this doesn't work when I use this in my views and then send directly the HTML to the Mandrill API.

How am I supposed to do this ? Is there a method in the `Mandrill::API` object that allows to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a MailChimp merge tag (probably pulled in from MailChimp templates you exported to your Mandrill account). For the same functionality in Mandrill, you need to add Mandrill's merge tag as described here: https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205583017-Can-I-add-an-automatic-unsubscribe-link-to-Mandrill-emails-